# Understanding ls -l output

Tags: ls

When I run `ls -lrt` command on a Unix folder , I get the following output

```
MyServer> ls -lrt
total 10
drwxr-x---   3 UnixUser  other        512 Jul 22  2011 FolderA
lrwxrwxrwx   1 UnixUser  other         42 Aug 23  2011 BEA -> ../../../Some/Folder/SOLARIS/BEA
```

I am not sure what are BEA and Perlx.x in these folders. They do not seem to be files nor folders. Why is there a arrow besides them pointing to somewhere else?

Comment: Symbolic link..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see `Perlx.x` but the `->` just means the file is a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), the equivalent of a windows shortcut. The file `BEA` in the current directory is a symbolic link to

```
../../../Some/Folder/SOLARIS/BEA
```

The `../` means the parent directory, so if you are for example in

```
/foo/bar/baz/dir
```

Then the link would be for

```
/foo/Some/Folder/SOLARIS/BEA
```

---

To illustrate:

```
$ cd /home/terdon/foo/bar/baz/dir/
$ ln -s ../../../file1 .
$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 11 Feb 28 06:16 file1 -> ../../file1
$ ls -l /home/terdon/foo/bar/
drwxr-xr-x 3 terdon terdon 4096 Feb 28 06:14 baz
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon    0 Feb 28 06:16 file1
```